# Available memory, respecting cgroups

Tags: linux, cgroups

I'm trying to accurately scale parallelism for a build process, where a set of invocations use a lot of memory.

Is there a good tool to find out the amount of memory that is actually available to the current process, including cgroups limits?

For CPUs, `nproc` does a reasonable job:

```
$ docker run --rm -it debian nproc
8
$ docker run --cpuset-cpus 1 --rm -it debian nproc
1
```

I'm looking for the equivalent to find the amount of memory actually available to the current cgroup (assuming that if someone wants to limit my build process, it will not have to share the cgroup), my best approach so far has been trial and error:

```
$ docker run --memory-swap 512M -m 512M --rm debian dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=100M count=1
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
$ docker run --memory-swap 512M -m 512M --rm debian dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1G count=1
geier@lime:~$ echo $?
137
```

Ideally this would work everywhere, even if cgroups imposes no actual limit, and use physical memory only, as the goal is to avoid overloading the machine with huge processes.